# How can I SELECT data that is exclusive?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a SELECT statement that will pull data that only exists once. I have two columns, ItemID and OfficeID, and I need to find items from the ItemID column that are only registered to one office. Items can have multiple rows, one for each office they are assigned to. So a single ItemID can have multiple rows if it is used in multiple offices. Can I use a select statement with COUNT, or is there a better way?

Can't think of a place to start, but I've used COUNT in varying ways.

Comment: Could you please add sample data, how tables looks like, your attempt and the desired result?

Comment: You sound like you are on the right track. `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses will do it.  If you post sample data (or at least, a table def), we can give you a working query.

Answer (score 0):

Using `HAVING` and `EXISTS` you can use the below query since *Items can have multiple rows, one for each office they are assigned to* which I read as an ItemID will *only* have multiple rows if it has multiple `OfficeID`. If there can be multiple rows for the same `OfficeID` just let us know.

```
select *
from table
where exists(select ItemID from table group by ItemID having count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must `group by ItemID` and in the `having` clause apply the condition `count(*) = 1`:

```
select ItemID
from tablename
group by ItemID
having count(*) = 1
```

or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.ItemID
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where ItemID = t.ItemID and OfficeID <> t.OfficeID
)
```

this will return all items for which there is not another row with the same `ItemID` but different `OfficeID`.